# Property of Extbase object returning NULL in FLUID, but only when calling directly

Tags: typo3

I'm facing a very strange problem: When debugging an object in FLUID with  all properties are shown. When trying to call some properties directly, they show their value. But on some properties the value is NULL, but only when calling directly.
e.g. {addresses.0.lastname} shows the lastname but {addresses.0.lng} doesn't show the value of "lng", though when calling {addresses} there is a value!?

ext_tables.sql:

```
    CREATE TABLE tx_pngooglemap_domain_model_address (
        uid int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        ....
        firstname varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        lastname varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        ....
        lat varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        lng varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        notes text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
```

Model:

```
    class Address extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
    {    
    /**
     * firstname
     *
     * @var string
     * @validate NotEmpty
     */
    protected $firstname = '';

    /**
     * lastname
     *
     * @var string
     * @validate NotEmpty
     */
    protected $lastname = '';

    /******************* some more properties ***/

    /**
     * lat
     *
     * @var string
     * @validate NotEmpty
     */
    protected $lat = '';

    /**
     * lng
     *
     * @var string
     * @validate NotEmpty
     */
    protected $lng = '';


    /**
     * Returns the firstname
     *
     * @return string $firstname
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the firstname
     *
     * @param string $firstname
     * @return void
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the lastname
     *
     * @return string $lastname
     */
    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the lastname
     *
     * @param string $lastname
     * @return void
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
    }

    /******************* some more getters and setters for properties ***/

    /**
     * Returns the lat
     *
     * @return string $lat
     */
    public function getLat()
    {
        return $lat->lat;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the lat
     *
     * @param string $lat
     * @return void
     */
    public function setLat($lat)
    {
        $this->lat = $lat;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the lng
     *
     * @return string $lng
     */
    public function getLng()
    {
        return $lng->lng;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the lng
     *
     * @param string $lng
     * @return void
     */
    public function setLng($lng)
    {
        $this->lng = $lng;
    }
    }
```

tca.php:

```
    'lastname' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:pngooglemap/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_pngooglemap_domain_model_address.lastname',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 30,
            'eval' => 'trim,required'
        ],
    ],
    'lat' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:pngooglemap/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_pngooglemap_domain_model_address.latitude',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 30,
            'eval' => 'trim'
        ]
    ],
    'lng' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:pngooglemap/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_pngooglemap_domain_model_address.longitude',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 30,
            'eval' => 'trim'
        ]
    ],
```

Controller:

```
public function listAction()
    {    
        $addresses = $this->addressRepository->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('addresses', $addresses);
    }
```

List.html:

```
    <html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
    <f:layout name="Default" />

    <f:section name="main">
        <f:debug>{addresses.0}</f:debug> => shows all fields with their values
        <f:debug>{addresses.0.lastname}</f:debug> => shows the lastname
        <f:debug>{addresses.0.lng}</f:debug> => shows "NULL" instead of "48.45673"
    </f:section>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this `return $lng->lng;` in your `getLng` function. This should be `return $this->lng;`

A debug of `addresses.0` shows the properties directly. `addresses.0.lng` uses the `getLng` function.